# fullpage js - disable navigation back to the landing page

Tags: html, css, fullpage.js

I am using fullPage JS on my website, and I have also enabled navigation the right side of the page. I have a landing page, and once scrolled down, I don't want to enable the users to be able to scroll back to the landing page. For this requirement, I am facing two issues:

1. I have disabled scrolling up on the second page so that the user can't scroll up. But I have noticed than on scrolling very fast the user can still reach the landing page. What is the fix for this?
2. I have enabled the navigation dots on the website, using which I can scroll to the very top. How can I disable navigation on the first dot?

Link to the website:
https://rimildeyjsr.github.io/st.anthony

I am also attaching a link to the github repository:  https://github.com/rimildeyjsr/st.anthony

Options used in the plugin :

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
                    //names for the anchors of the pages
                    anchors:['welcome','home','administration_page','faculty_section','staff_section'],
                    navigation: true,
                    navigationPosition: 'right',
                    fixedElements: '#toggle,#overlay',

                    afterLoad : function(anchorLink,index) {
                        //after loading a section, perform these functions

                        if (index == 1 || anchorLink == 'welcome'){
                            //show the other sections now that the page has loaded
                            $('#fp-nav').hide();
                            $('#section1').show();
                            $('#section2').show();
                            $('#section3').show();
                            $('#section4').show();
                            $('#toggle').hide();

                        }
                        if (index == 2 || anchorLink == 'home'){
                            $('#fp-nav').show();
                            $('#toggle').show();
                            if (window.innerWidth < 480) {
                                $('.school-logo2').fadeIn();
                            }
                            $('.school-name').addClass('come-in');
                                slideEffect();

                            $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false,'up');
                            $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(false, 'up');
                        }

                        if(index == 3 || anchorLink == 'administration_page'){
                            $('#fp-nav').show();
                            $('#toggle').show();
                            $('.offscreen-logo').addClass('come-in-logo').one(animationEnd,function(){
                               display();
                            });
                            $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true,'up');
                            $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(true, 'up');
                        }

                        if(index == 4 || anchorLink == 'faculty_section') {
                            $('#fp-nav').show();
                            $('#toggle').show();
                            $('#section3 .section-heading').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
                            $('#section3 .card').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
                            $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true,'up');
                            $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(true, 'up');
                        }
                        if(index == 5 || anchorLink == 'staff_section') {
                            $('#fp-nav').show();
                            $('#toggle').show();
                            $('#section4 .section-heading').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
                            $('#section4 .card').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
                            $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true,'up');
                            $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(true, 'up');
                        }
                    }

                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unable to replicate issue #1, in which you say you can scroll quickly and still reach the first slide. I've tried scrolling as fast as I can in both Chrome & Safari on desktop and wasn't able to reach the first slide after the initial scroll down.

If you're looking to hide the first pagination dot, you could target the `li` using `:first-of-type`. In your case, you could add the following code:

`#fp-nav ul li:first-of-type { display: none; }`

If you're looking to keep it, but just disable the functionality, you can use `pointer-events`, in which case you'd use:

`#fp-nav ul li:first-of-type { pointer-events: none; }`

Comment: Thanks @Matthew Beckman, the pointer event worked to disable the pagination. For the first issue, from the bottom slides if i scroll up, without waiting for any page to load, just like skipping through the sections, then you can reach the landing page.